# Neo4j: Cypher order by max value of connection's array

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So, I have folloving query:

`MATCH result=(({uuid: "056d7d6c-4eb1-11e8-a2d0-3035adbe14a4"})-[r:mailed]-(p)) RETURN result LIMIT 5`.

It should fetch all the nodes that has mailed connection with the given node. Now, I need to sort them. The problem is that the timestamp is in array that contains timestamps of all messages. I want to sort the result by the largest value in timestamp array.

Is it possible? How would that query look? I've tried `ORDER BY max(r.timestamp)`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WITH](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/with/) to group paths by the `max(r.timestamp)` value, then order and return the desired values:

```
MATCH path=({uuid: "056d7d6c-4eb1-11e8-a2d0-3035adbe14a4"})-[r:mailed]->(p) 
WITH path, max(r.timestamp) as maxtimestamp
order by maxtimestamp
RETURN path LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Thank you, however I am getting following error: `MIN/MAX can only handle values of Comparable type, or null. This was a :r.timestamp`